# I want to check if index of ArrayList is declared, without using get

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I try to get an element from an `Arraylist` using an index, and check if it is empty or not.

I tried:

```
if(!ArrayList.get(index)) {
    // do something
}
```

And it gets *Index out of Bounds* exception.

Of course I can use try-catch, but I'd like to know if there is any other way of doing this without using try-catch?

I think I can do it more simply, but I can't. I tried to read the API documentation, but it seems like there is no such thing as what I want to do.

Comment: oh and, i tryed if(ArrayList.get(index)==null) ... and it also stop by error!

Comment: `index >= list.size()`?

Comment: Is your `ArrayList` *instance* called `ArrayList`? How confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check the list's [`size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size--) (and of course, it must also be non-negative):

```
if (index >= 0 && index < myList.size()) {
    // Do something with myList.get(index)
}
```

Comment: myList.size() > index

Comment: oh boi, i am idiot... ill accept answer after 10minuate!

Comment: @MauricePerry grr... stupid typo. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(index < ArrayList.size() && ArrayList.get(index) != null)
```

Comment: okay, i tryed to reverse like : if (index > ArrayList.size() && ArrayList.get(index) == null) and its crashed, hmm did i typo?

Comment: @ChangWonJeongJuicycool If `index > ArrayList.size()` then `ArrayList.get(index)` won't *ever* return `null` or even anything *comparable to* `null`.

Comment: @Biffen ahh, thats why i got error when try to get() wrong index? cool! if it is, now im perfectly understand, thanks to you!